# The for loop doesn't rbind() the vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector, rbind

I need help with this for loop. It seems to be working, I get no errors, but at the end it doesn't insert the vector "row.toadd" into the data frame for every iteration. But when I write the rbind() function after the for loop has looped through it binds the last vector that was created in the loop and inserts it into the data frame. But I want it to do it for every iteration in the for loop! When I write "row.toadd" there is a vector for the last iteration just like I want it so it's the last part that isn't working. I think it's really strange because I used a similar code before and it worked.

```
  for(i in 1:length(event.files)){
event.temp <- fromJSON(file=event.files[i])

shot.index <- which(unlist(lapply(event.temp,function(x) x$type$name))=="Shot")


shots.France <- shot.index[which(unlist(lapply(shot.index,function(x) event.temp[[x]]$team$name))=="France")]

shots.France.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=11))
colnames(shots.France.df) <- c("Possession","Player","X.Shot","Y.Shot",
                              "Shot.Type","xG","keypassid","X.KeyPass","Y.KeyPass","Shot.Outcome","Shot.Foot")



if(length(shots.France)!=0){
  for(p in 1:length(shots.France)){
    shots.France.temp <- event.temp[[shots.France[p]]]
    possession <- shots.France.temp$possession
    shooter <- shots.France.temp$player$name
    shots.location <- shots.France.temp$location
    shots.type <- shots.France.temp$shot$technique$name
    shots.xg <- ifelse("statsbomb_xg" %!in% names(shots.France.temp$shot),NA, shots.France.temp$shot$statsbomb_xg)
    keypass <- ifelse("key_pass_id" %!in% names(shots.France.temp$shot),NA,shots.France.temp$shot$key_pass_id)
    keypass.location <- if(!is.na(keypass)){
      as.vector(unlist(pass.team1.df[which(pass.team1.df$passid==keypass),c("X.Pass","Y.Pass")]))
    }else{
      c(NA,NA)
    }
    shots.outcome <- shots.France.temp$shot$outcome$name
    body.part <- shots.France.temp$shot$body_part$name

    row.toadd <- c(possession,shooter,shots.location,shots.type,shots.xg,keypass,keypass.location[1],keypass.location[2],shots.outcome,body.part)

    shots.France[p,] <- row.toadd 
    shots.France.df <- rbind(shots.France.df,row.toadd)
    shots.France.list <- list(shots.France.df)

  }
}
}
```

Comment: You'd probably get help more easily if you broke down the problem to its bare essentials. Oh yeah, and if you provided some reprex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but I guess you refer to the folowing line in your inner for loop from your code listening.

```
shots.France.df <- rbind(shots.France.df, row.toadd)
```

However, you also have the following code line in your outer for loop.

```
shots.France.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=11))
```

I therefore guess that you simply overwrite the data frame you create in the inner for loop. I therefore conclude that the code works if you move

```
shots.France.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=11))
colnames(shots.France.df) <- c("Possession","Player","X.Shot","Y.Shot",
                          "Shot.Type","xG","keypassid","X.KeyPass","Y.KeyPass","Shot.Outcome","Shot.Foot")
```

out of the for loop. This just means that

```
shots.France.df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=1,ncol=11))
colnames(shots.France.df) <- c("Possession","Player","X.Shot","Y.Shot",
                         "Shot.Type","xG","keypassid","X.KeyPass","Y.KeyPass","Shot.Outcome","Shot.Foot")


 for(i in 1:length(event.files)){
event.temp <- fromJSON(file=event.files[i])
# Rest of your code.
```

I hope this helps.

PS: Can you please format the code properly the next time you ask a question? Your code is hard to read.